# Fix plugin Fatal error in EXEC-php

Tags: php, wordpress

I encountered this error after I upgraded my WordPress version:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'new' (T_NEW) in
>
> C:\xampp\htdocs\titaniumcobra\wp-content\plugins\exec-php\exec-php.php on 
>           line 22

This is the code in line 22:

```
$GLOBALS['g_execphp_manager'] =& new ExecPhp_Manager();
```

How can I debug this problem?

Comment: We will need to see line 22 of exec-php.php to be able to help. Best to give a few lines though, maybe line 20 to 26 or similar.

Comment: Sorry for that, I already edited my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the =& in line 22. It seems like this is a very outdated plugin that you should replace if possible. It seems like it allows you to execute user-contributed code and as it's out of date this could be a security risk.

That said, if you remove the & it'll likely start working.

```
$GLOBALS['g_execphp_manager'] = new ExecPhp_Manager();
```

Comment: I have the same problem. But there's lot & in all included pages. Is there is any alternative way?

Comment: Other locations where you have to remove the "&", possibly with a "search and replace":
/wp-content/plugins/exec-php/includes/manager.php (4 lines)
/wp-content/plugins/exec-php/includes/admin.php (several lines)
/wp-content/plugins/exec-php/includes/cache.php (2 lines)

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a right solution , I think something needs to be updated?May be the PHP VERSION is creating issue???